# How to add users to specific repositories?

Tags: plasticscm

We recently moved from Unity's collab to Plastic, our team is about 10 people and we have a couple of projects. However we don't want all 10 to have access to all the projects. How can we assign users to repositories the same way we were doing so at collab?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the Security guide, this scenario might be what you are looking for: https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/security/plastic-scm-version-control-security-guide#Openuparepositorytoaspecificgroup

You can open up repositories to specific users or whole groups, this management need to be done from the PlasticSCM interface as the guide shows.